# Patching in pytest before import

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Given a module

**some_module.py**

```
_foo = Foo(config)
def do_foo():
    return _foo.foo()
```

`Foo.__init__` raises an exception, so I am not able to write a test since the exception is already raised at import time in `some_module.py`.
I want to patch the module to replace `_foo` with an object of another type, say `TestFoo`. I tried using `mock.patch`, but this does not work because the exception is already raised before the patching is applied.

I am coming from java where I would have injected through constructor while testing, which is easy. What are my options in Python?

Comment: import the object in the scope of the patch